# HttpWebRequest an Unicode characters

Tags: c#, asp.net, httpwebrequest

I am using this code:

```
HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
string result = null;
using (HttpWebResponse resp = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse())
{
   StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(resp.GetResponseStream());
   result = reader.ReadToEnd();
   reader.Close();
}
```

In `result` I get text like `003cbr /003e003cbr /003e` (I think this should be 2 line breaks instead). I tried with the 2, 3 parameter versions of `Streamreader` but the string was the same. (the request returns a json string)

Why am I getting those characters, and how can I avoid them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not really clear what that text is, but you're not specifying an encoding at the moment. What content encoding is the server using? `StreamReader` will default to UTF-8.

It sounds like *actually* you're getting some sort of oddly-encoded HTML, as U+003C is `<` and U+003E is `>`, giving `<br /><br />` as the content. That's not JSON...

Two tests:

- Use `WebClient.DownloadString`, which will detect the right encoding to use
- See what gets shown using the same URL in a browser

EDIT: Okay, now that I've seen the text, it's *actually* got:

```
\u003cbr /\u003e
```

The `\u` part is important here - that's part of the JSON which states that the next four characters form ar the hex representation of a UTF-16 code unit.

Any JSON API used to parse that text should perform the unescaping for you.

Comment: '...{ "content": "some text <br /><br />" }...'. This is JSON. And I tried the Streamreader with every encoding.

Comment: @e-MEE: Ah, so that text is there, but with other text as well. That wasn't clear. When you say you're seeing "003cbr /" - how are you detecting that? What are you looking at `result` in?

Comment: well, actually this request is a Google+ API activities.list request. And the activity content contains stuff like "003cbr /"

Comment: @e-MEE: That sounds like the actual content contains that then - so how were you seeing `<br />` as per your first comment? I wouldn't expect the browser to do that for you. It's still really unclear where you're seeing what, and how you're observing it.

Comment: try http://code.google.com/apis/explorer activities.get with id: `z13qj5sqbv3ahr3mr23ev5mi5vjvvjuvk`. The API Explorer shows the characters correct but, in C# don't get the same string.

Comment: @e-MEE: Okay, see my edit. Basically you should use a JSON parser to parse the data and unescape the characters. Note that the API explorer is performing the decoding for you for convenience.